system verilog code error
I developed this code for a Graph convolutional network (GCN) module in system verilog:
module GCN
  #(parameter FEATURE_COLS = 96,
    parameter WEIGHT_ROWS = 96,
    parameter FEATURE_ROWS = 6,
    parameter WEIGHT_COLS = 3,
    parameter FEATURE_WIDTH = 5,
    parameter WEIGHT_WIDTH = 5,
    parameter DOT_PROD_WIDTH = 16,
    parameter ADDRESS_WIDTH = 13,
    parameter COUNTER_WEIGHT_WIDTH = $clog2(WEIGHT_COLS),
    parameter COUNTER_FEATURE_WIDTH = $clog2(FEATURE_ROWS),
    parameter MAX_ADDRESS_WIDTH = 2,
    parameter NUM_OF_NODES = 6,          
    parameter COO_NUM_OF_COLS = 6,          
    parameter COO_NUM_OF_ROWS = 2,          
    parameter COO_BW = $clog2(COO_NUM_OF_COLS)  
)
(
  input logic clk,  // Clock
  input logic reset,    // Reset 
  input logic start,
  input logic [WEIGHT_WIDTH-1:0] data_in [0:WEIGHT_ROWS-1], //FM and WM Data
  input logic [COO_BW - 1:0] coo_in [0:1], //row 0 and row 1 of the COO Stream

  output logic [COO_BW - 1:0] coo_address, // The column of the COO Matrix 
  output logic [ADDRESS_WIDTH-1:0] read_address, // The Address to read the FM and WM Data
  output logic enable_read, // Enabling the Read of the FM and WM Data
  output logic done, // Done signal indicating that all the calculations have been completed
  output logic [MAX_ADDRESS_WIDTH - 1:0] max_addi_answer [0:FEATURE_ROWS - 1] // The answer to the argmax and matrix multiplication 
); 

    // Internal signals
    logic [FEATURE_WIDTH-1:0] feature_matrix [0:FEATURE_ROWS-1][0:FEATURE_COLS-1];
    logic [WEIGHT_WIDTH-1:0] weight_matrix [0:WEIGHT_ROWS-1][0:WEIGHT_COLS-1];
    logic [DOT_PROD_WIDTH-1:0] transformed_features [0:FEATURE_ROWS-1][0:WEIGHT_COLS-1];
    logic [DOT_PROD_WIDTH-1:0] aggregated_features [0:FEATURE_ROWS-1];
    logic [COUNTER_FEATURE_WIDTH-1:0] node_counter;
    logic [COUNTER_WEIGHT_WIDTH-1:0] weight_counter;
    logic processing;

    // Pipelining flip-flops for inputs and outputs
    always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset) begin
            enable_read <= 1'b0;
            done <= 1'b0;
        end else if (start) begin
            enable_read <= 1'b1;
            processing <= 1'b1;
        end else if (processing) begin
            enable_read <= 1'b0;
        end
    end

    // Reading COO matrix
    always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset) begin
            coo_address <= 0;
        end else if (enable_read) begin
            coo_address <= coo_address + 1;
        end
    end

    // Feature transformation
    always_comb begin
        for (int i = 0; i < FEATURE_ROWS; i++) begin
            for (int j = 0; j < WEIGHT_COLS; j++) begin
                transformed_features[i][j] = '0;
                for (int k = 0; k < FEATURE_COLS; k++) begin
                    transformed_features[i][j] += feature_matrix[i][k] * weight_matrix[k][j];
                end
            end
        end
    end

    // Aggregation (vector addition)
    always_comb begin
        for (int i = 0; i < FEATURE_ROWS; i++) begin
            aggregated_features[i] = '0;
            for (int j = 0; j < COO_NUM_OF_COLS; j++) begin
                aggregated_features[i] += transformed_features[coo_in[0][j]][coo_in[1][j]];
            end
        end
    end

    // Argmax function
    always_comb begin
        for (int i = 0; i < FEATURE_ROWS; i++) begin
            max_addi_answer[i] = '0;
            for (int j = 1; j < WEIGHT_COLS; j++) begin
                if (aggregated_features[i] < transformed_features[i][j]) begin
                    max_addi_answer[i] = j;
                end
            end
        end
    end

    // Done signal
    always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset) begin
            done <= 1'b0;
        end else if (processing) begin
            done <= 1'b1;
        end
    end         

endmodule 

I ran this code for synthesis via dc_shell and got the following error:
Warning:  path/Lab4/GCN/systemVerilog//verilog.sv:94: signed to unsigned assignment occurs. (VER-318)
Warning:  path/GCN/systemVerilog//verilog.sv:101: Net done or a directly connected net may be driven by more than one process or block. (ELAB-405)

Inferred memory devices in process
    in routine GCN line 45 in file
        'path/GCN/systemVerilog//verilog.sv'.
===============================================================================
|    Register Name    |   Type    | Width | Bus | MB | AR | AS | SR | SS | ST |
===============================================================================
|   processing_reg    | Flip-flop |   1   |  N  | N  | N  | N  | N  | N  | N  |
|   enable_read_reg   | Flip-flop |   1   |  N  | N  | Y  | N  | N  | N  | N  |
|      done_reg       |   Latch   |   1   |  N  | N  | Y  | N  | -  | -  | -  |
===============================================================================
Inferred memory devices in process
    in routine GCN line 58 in file
        'path/GCN/systemVerilog//verilog.sv'.
===============================================================================
|    Register Name    |   Type    | Width | Bus | MB | AR | AS | SR | SS | ST |
===============================================================================
|   coo_address_reg   | Flip-flop |   3   |  Y  | N  | Y  | N  | N  | N  | N  |
===============================================================================
Inferred memory devices in process
    in routine GCN line 101 in file
        'path/GCN/systemVerilog//verilog.sv'.
===============================================================================
|    Register Name    |   Type    | Width | Bus | MB | AR | AS | SR | SS | ST |
===============================================================================
|      done_reg2      | Flip-flop |   1   |  N  | N  | Y  | N  | N  | N  | N  |
===============================================================================
Warning:  path/GCN/systemVerilog//verilog.sv:45: Netlist for always_ff block contains a latch. (ELAB-978)
Error:  path/GCN/systemVerilog//verilog.sv:101: Net 'done' or a directly connected net is driven by more than one source, and not all drivers are three-state. (ELAB-366)
Presto compilation terminated with 1 errors.

I am very new to system verilog/verilog and memory devices. Any help will be appriciated.

why do you say that Inferred memory devices in process message is an error?

The inferred memory message is not an error.
The error message is later on in that trace, specifically:
Error:  path/GCN/systemVerilog//verilog.sv:101: 
Net 'done' or a directly connected net is driven by more than one source

You have a net called done which is driven from more than one source.
Looking at your code, you have a stray assignment to the done signal in the first always block (line 45). Presumably a copy and paste mistake. This also explains the inferred latch warning as well. Replacing the done on this line with what I presume is meant to be processing will fix both the error and the warning.
    // Pipelining flip-flops for inputs and outputs
    always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset) begin
            enable_read <= 1'b0;
            done <= 1'b0;   <<<<<<<<<<<<< Here <<<<<<

